# Swift 3, SpriteKit, Google Interstitial ad never ready

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, admob, swift3

This question has been asked and answered multiple times here.  And i've read them all, implemented all suggestions, and still it does not work.  I'm currently doing it with a `NotificationObserver` and the ad is created, however it always returns `false` for `isReady`.  Please let me know if anything sticks out.

**GameViewController**

```
var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
```

*In `viewDidLoad`*

```
interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showInterstitial), name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "showInterAd"), object: nil);
```

*Ad functions*

```
func showInterstitial(){
    if (interstitial!.isReady) {
        self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }else{
        print("ad not ready?")
    }
}

func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
    print("making ad")
    let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-6956068899232786/9340371153")
    interstitial.delegate = self
    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
    interstitial.load(request)
    return interstitial
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}
```

**GameScene.swift**

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "showInterAd"), object: nil)
```

All functions get called at correct times, but the ad just never becomes ready.  I have triple checked the `adUnitID`, and tried on multiple devices/simulators.

Comment: Have you tried putting the second line of your viewDidLoad code into viewWillLayoutSubviews?

Comment: No, but that code doesn't do anything with views or positioning.  What grounds to have to support that idea?

Comment: You're supposed to add notification observers in viewWillLayoutSubviews (that's what a tutorial I read a while ago used)

Comment: The notification observer works.  But I Just realized I forgot to put that function in the post, but I know that's working.  Like I said, all functions get called, I've confirmed with what it being printed to the log.  The ad just doesn't display because it's "not ready". And I'm not sure why a NotificationObserver should go in `willLayoutSubviews`. Doesn't make much sense to me. What tutorial told you that?  That override function is specifically for positioning and display. As the name says. _layout_

Comment: The viewWillLayoutSubviews bit isn't that big a deal - it works both ways. As for your issue, have you tried waiting for an extended period of time? I can't compare it to my code until I get back to my computer, so I'll try to suggest things for now.

Comment: Well, the first time i load the ad is in `viewDidLoad`.  And i don't try to display it for the first time until at least 20 seconds later.  I know it doesn't take that long.

Comment: Does the first ad work?

Comment: None are ever displayed.  The notification is called at the end of a game level, which at the soonest can be every 10-20 seconds.  In my previous apps, which weren't using SpriteKit, i implemented the ads with no issue.  And they always seem to load in 1-3 second max.

Comment: Is the game very intensive?

Comment: Not at all.  Very basic.

Comment: @Nik  Well i figured it out, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

So i've got it working.  I do not know why this worked, and i'm assuming it has nothing to do with the app itself, but a bug or something within AdMob.

The fix was to replace the `ad_unit_id` with a different one from one of my other apps, which then made the ad become ready and display.  I was then able to replace the `ad_unit_id` back to the correct one for this app and it still works.

It's like it needed one that had been used before to *jumpstart* it in to working.  It's got me baffled, but hopefully this helps someone else.